# Expected primary expression before ']' token ...... line 10 column 21

Tags: c++

My code is as below.  I get the 'expected primary expression before ']' token' error at line number 10, column 21.  How do I rectify this error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    void insertion_sort ( int  c[]) ;
    int main () {

      int  ch [] =  { 314,463,25,46,24,554,99} ;    
      insertion_sort( ch[] );   
      cout<<ch;

      return 0;
    }

    void insertion_sort ( int c [] ){

     int size =0 , temp  , i , j;
     while( c[size] != '\0' )
     {
       ++size;
     }

     for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i){
        for ( j = i+1 ; j < size ; ++j ){
            if ( c[i]<c[j] ){
              c[i]=temp;        
              c[i]=c[j];
              c[j]=c[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return ;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just use `insertion_sort( ch);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As R Sahu said

> Just use `insertion_sort(ch);`

this is an answer to your question what I want to add is that it is unnecessary to write return in your function so you may omit it.

Remember that the name of an array is an address to a first element of an array.